# How to Set Boolean Field Using JDOM

Tags: java, xml, boolean, setter, jdom

Just a quick question, does anyone know what the correct method to use is when you want to change the value of a boolean field within an xml file using JDOM in java?

For example, I know if I want to change the value of a string field, all I have to do is:

```
documentLevelFieldChild.getChild("Value").setText("This is the new text");
```

And I tried,

```
documentLevelFieldChild.getChild("Value").setValue(false);
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

I tried looking up the API and found a method related to getting the bool value, but nothing related to setting it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
documentLevelFieldChild.getChild("Value").setText("false");
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. The type field specifies whether it's a string or boolen, etc. The actual value field is just text. Makes sense. Thank you!